# Can't run libusb on windows QT

Tags: c++, qt, libusb, libusb-win32

**Development evnironment:** 
Qt Creator 4.0.2
Основан на Qt 5.7.0 (MSVC 2013, 32 бита)

**Operating system:**
WIndows 7 x64

**Error:**
`:-1: ошибка: No rule to make target 'libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0/lib/gcc/libusb.a', needed by 'debug\TestUsb.exe'.  Stop.`

I want to use libusb in my project. I download and unzip `libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0` in project folder. Then i modify project file:

```
LIBS += libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0/lib/gcc/libusb.a
INCLUDEPATH += libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0/include
DEPENDPATH += libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0/include
PRE_TARGETDEPS += libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0/lib/gcc/libusb.a
```

And this is my `main.c` file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <lusb0_usb.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    usb_dev_handle *USB_Device = NULL;
    struct usb_bus *usbBus;
    struct usb_device *usbDevice;

    for (usbBus = usb_get_busses(); usbBus; usbBus = usbBus->next)
      {
          for (usbDevice = usbBus->devices; usbDevice; usbDevice = usbDevice->next)
          {
              pfintf("0x%h 0x%h", usbDevice->descriptor.idVendor, usbDevice->descriptor.idProduct);
              if ((usbDevice->descriptor.idVendor == 0x0483) && (usbDevice->descriptor.idProduct == 0x5750))
              {
                  USB_Device = usb_open(usbDevice);
              }
          }
      }

    printf("Hello world");
}
```

I don't know whats wrong. I can't find any solution in internet.

Comment: Try to use absolute paths

Comment: @MichaelO. hmmm. It's works. But I don't whant to use absolute path (we must work in team on different computers)

Comment: Try to add `$$PWD/` before path

Comment: Program will fail with code 0x135 (but compiled)

Comment: Add `PRO_DIR=$$PWD` at beginning and add `$$PRO_DIR/` before paths.

Comment: Also LIBS should be like `LIBS += -L$$PRO_DIR/libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0/lib/gcc/libusb.a`

Comment: @MichaelO. `error 0x0135` As I can understand - it's mean "missing DLL in system". I don't know how to install DLL in system (zip haven't instruction)